# Designing PDF with HTML in WPF application

Tags: wpf, pdf

Is it possible to design a pdf using HTML and js in a WPF application(C#). I tried using iTextSharp by taking a image of the control i want to export and then pasted in the pdf. It worked, but the problem is the control has to be visible. So, lets say if there is a listview in that control and that listview doesn't fits in one window, then whole listview doesn't gets exported. Any ideas how to approach?

This is so far I've done for exporting ListView to pdf.

```
ListView item = list;
            double width = item.ActualWidth;
            double height = item.ActualHeight;
            Document doc = new Document(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(1200f, 700f));
            String filePath;
            string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\export\\" ;
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            filePath = path + "\\Test_.pdf";
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Append));
            doc.Open();
            RenderTargetBitmap bmpCopied = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)Math.Round(width + 100), (int)Math.Round(height + 50), 0, 0, PixelFormats.Default);

            DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
            using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
            {
                item.Background = Brushes.White;
                VisualBrush visualBrush = new VisualBrush(item);
                drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.White, null, new Rect(new Point(), new Size(width + 100, height + 50)));
                drawingContext.DrawRectangle(visualBrush, null, new Rect(new Point(), new Size(width + 100, height + 50)));
            }

            bmpCopied.Render(drawingVisual);

            item.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
            byte[] data;
            JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmpCopied));
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                encoder.Save(ms);
                data = ms.ToArray();
            }

            iTextSharp.text.Image pdfImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(data);
            doc.Add(pdfImage);
            doc.Close();
```

The pdf gets created, but opening the pdf shows error. Secondly, my ListView is scrollable, will all the items be shown in the pdf?. I just need to get it working. Any way would be ok for me

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Generally speaking questions on this site have a better chance of getting answered if you ask them using as many specifics as possible and explaining what you've already tried. You've mentioned 3 completely different technologies here (PDF, HTML/JS and XAML) but it's not really clear exactly what you're trying to do other than you want to somehow use them together to design something. Everything's possible to some extent...what's the exact technical problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I need to export my XAML element to PDF. I already solved that using iTextSharp by having a first rendering XAML control to bmp and then converting it to pdf as explained above in the question. But the problem here is if that control is not visible/partially visible then pdf is not showing the complete control,for eg, only the visible items of listview are being shown in the pdf and not the complete control

Comment: Is this even possible?